# Karaf container, Rest WS and Spring security

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-security, apache-karaf, dosgi

I'm trying to applied security (Basic Authentication e.g.) to my Rest-WS.
Those WS are published through DOSGi in a Karaf container.

```
<!--
    Register VCPENetworkManager as OSGi Service
  -->       
<bean id="vcpeNetworkManager" class="org.opennaas.extensions.vcpe.manager.VCPENetworkManager"/>
<service ref="vcpeNetworkManager" interface="org.opennaas.extensions.vcpe.manager.IVCPENetworkManager">
    <service-properties>
        <!-- Rest -->   
        <entry key="service.exported.interfaces" value="*"/>
        <entry key="service.exported.configs" value="org.apache.cxf.rs"/>
        <entry key="service.exported.intents" value="HTTP"/>        
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.ws.address" value="${ws.rest.url}/vcpenetwork"/>  
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

I need help why I don't know what dependencies add in the bundle that publish the ws or how or where include the config files of spring. I have always worked with an application server.

Thanks,

Comment: Spring Security has very well written documentation. You can start here for dependencies http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#appendix-dependencies , and here for config: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-config

Comment: Yes, I have worked before with spring in a typical webb app but my problem is how configure it in a osgi container.

Comment: Sorry, I complitely missed OSGi environment.

Comment: how do you deploy your application in Karaf, as a WAB?

Comment: No, I have a bundle with one interface and his implementation and the Rest annotations. When I register the service, I register the service with the DOSGi properties (see code in the previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CXF for DOSGi I'd suggest using it with Blueprint, it's a Spring like XML syntax and works best in a OSGi environment.